# How to do selection in web from Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, http, python-requests-html

I trying to build a web scraper in python.
The website shows a list of entries. Via an dropdown menu, I can choose the order of the list.

The html looks like this:

```
...
<select name="sortOrder"
    id="search-toolbar-sort-by"
    onchange="$('#sortOrder').val($('#search-toolbar-sort-by').val());
              $('#searchFilterForm').submit();
              console.log('value:' + $('#sortOrder').val());
              ga('send', 'event', 'MySearch', 'clicked sorting');
              console.log('nach ga');">
  <option value="relevant">relevant</option>
  <option value="newest">newest</option>
  <option value="start date">start date</option>
</select>
...
```

My web skills are very low and I do not know what the Javascript part in 'onchange' is doing.

In the network-analysis tool of the browser I can see it is doing an POST request.
But when I take the URL of the POST request and paste it by hand, I still get the default order.

I am looking for a lightweight solution to get the list in the right order from my python script.
The module requests seem not to be powerful enough. But maybe it is realizable with requests_html(?).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you're only looking to get the "sorted" list, you're better off scraping each `option` value and then sorting a list of strings via Python (https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-sort-a-list-of-strings-list-sort-tutorial-examples/)

Comment: The list goes over multiple pages. With our solution I would have to load all n pages, just to check if there is a new entry.

Comment: webscrapping is never lightweight ;-) however you are loocking at the code but the scrapper looks at the dom loaded. Your are sure you have a dom with the entries ?